# Why doesn't ng-submit work after $state.transitionTo('login');

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-promise

I'm using ui-router for routing in an angular application.  In an httpInterceptor, I'm checking for authentication rejections, and if I find one, transitioning to the 'login' route.  Everything works seemingly, but even though the login button works initially (before any other page is accessed), after transitionTo fires, the login button's form's ng-submit does not fire, as if the controller isn't loaded, but there are no errors.  Here's what I'm using to transition:

```
var pendingAuthRequest;
this.responseError = function(response) {
    if (response.status === 401 { //slightly truncated for brevity
        var defer = $q.defer();
        if (!pendingAuthRequest) { 
            pendingAuthRequest = AuthenticationService.refreshToken();
        }
        pendingAuthRequest.then(
            function() {
                pendingAuthRequest = undefined;
                defer.resolve(response);
            },
            function() {
                pendingAuthRequest = undefined;
                defer.reject(response);
            }
        );
        return defer.promise.then(
            function() {
                return ResolverService.get.$http(response.config);
            },
            function() {
                //probably a righter way to do this
                ResolverService.get.$state.transitionTo('login');
                return $q.reject(response);
            }
        );
    }
    else {
        return $q.reject(response);
    }
};
```

Here's the route:

```
$stateProvider.state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'components/user/login.html',
    controller: 'loginComponentCtrl as login',
    data: {
        title: 'Dashboard',
        titleIcon: 'fa-tachometer',
        noAuth: true
    }
});
```

Here's the login button setup, which won't be surprising.

```
<form name="login-form" ng-submit="login.login()">
...
    <button type="submit" ng-if="login.processing !== true">Login</button>
```

And lastly, the login controller

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('ctk.components.login', []);

    app.controller('loginComponentCtrl', ['AuthenticationService', loginComponentCtrl]);

    function loginComponentCtrl(AuthenticationService) {
        var self = this;

        self.processing = false;

        self.login = function() {
            self.processing = true;

            AuthenticationService.login(self.username, self.password)
                .then(function(success) {

                }, function(failureReason) {
                    self.errorMessage = failureReason;
                })
                .finally(function() {
                    self.processing = false;
                });
        };
    }
}());
```

Again, the login page, when initially loaded, works fine, but not after being transitioned to with the above snippet.  A refresh resolves the issue.  Any idea what might be going on here?